# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3

Tags: java, android, json

I want to insert data to database with json but app crash when i press submit
i have no idea how to fix this can you help me?................................................................................................................................................................

I have used this website as my guide 
https://androidjson.com/android-php-send-data-mysql-database/

activity_laporan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"


    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Laporan"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Perkakasan"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_title">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_nama"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:ems="15"
            android:hint="Nama Penuh"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_nokp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="15"
            android:hint="No Kad Pengenalan"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_notel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="15"
            android:hint="No Tel"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_komputer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Komputer" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_monitor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Monitor" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_keyboard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Keyboard" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_mouse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Mouse" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_printer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Printer" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_scanner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Scanner" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_lcdprojector"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="LCD Projector" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_ups"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="UPS" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_rangkaian"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Peralatan Rangkaian" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_ulasan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="Ulasan"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_res"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_ulasan" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_res"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_sub"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_ulasan" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Laporan.java

```
package com.example.e_aduanjabatanict;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Laporan extends AppCompatActivity {
    String ServerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/jabatanict/get_data.php";
    CheckBox komp, moni, keyb, mous, prin, scan, lcdp, ups, rang;
    EditText nama, nokp, notel, ulasan;
    Button reset, submit;
    String TempNokp, TempNama, TempNotel, TempUlasan;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_laporan);

        nokp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_nokp);
        nama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_nama);
        notel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_notel);
        ulasan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_ulasan);


        //reset Button
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_res);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sub);
        komp = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_komputer);
        moni = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_monitor);
        keyb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_keyboard);
        mous = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_mouse);
        prin = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_printer);
        scan = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_scanner);
        lcdp = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_lcdprojector);
        ups = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_ups);
        rang = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_rangkaian);

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nama.setText("");
                nokp.setText("");
                notel.setText("");
                ulasan.setText("");

                if (komp.isChecked()) {
                    komp.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (moni.isChecked()) {
                    moni.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (keyb.isChecked()) {
                    keyb.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (mous.isChecked()) {
                    mous.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (prin.isChecked()) {
                    prin.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (scan.isChecked()) {
                    scan.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (lcdp.isChecked()) {
                    lcdp.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (ups.isChecked()) {
                    ups.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (rang.isChecked()) {
                    rang.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });

        //submit
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GetData();

                InsertData(TempNokp, TempNama, TempNotel, TempUlasan);

            }
        });
    }




        public void GetData(){

            TempNokp = nama.getText().toString();

            TempNama = nokp.getText().toString();

            TempNotel = notel.getText().toString();

            TempUlasan = ulasan.getText().toString();
        }

        public void InsertData(final String nokp, final String nama, final String notel, final String ulasan){

            class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    String NokpHolder = nokp ;
                    String NamaHolder = nama ;
                    String NotelHolder = notel ;
                    String UlasanHolder = ulasan ;

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nokp", NokpHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", NamaHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notel", NotelHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ulasan", UlasanHolder));

                    try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                    return "Data Inserted Successfully";
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    Toast.makeText(Laporan.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

            sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(nokp, nama, notel, ulasan);
    }

}
```

This error show after i press submit

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: com.example.e_aduanjabatanict, PID: 8913
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair;
        at com.example.e_aduanjabatanict.Laporan$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Laporan.java:136)
        at com.example.e_aduanjabatanict.Laporan$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Laporan.java:125)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.e_aduanjabatanict.Laporan$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Laporan.java:136) 
        at com.example.e_aduanjabatanict.Laporan$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(Laporan.java:125) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.e_aduanjabatanict-rCqKaOCDBhpZ9c3N8IEDkg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8913 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair"` - add this jar to your classpath

Comment: `import` is **not** the same as `classpath`

Comment: may i know how to add to ```classpath``` ?

Comment: try searching this for yourself.